# Generating hybrid atomic orbitals for Boron

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, orbitals

My professor was showing us how to form hybrid atomic orbitals for Boron by taking a linear combination of rotated 2p orbitals and 2s orbitals (of Boron). This was done in a particular manner such that the geometry of BH3 is correct. We were given BH3:

[image]

He proposed 3 new hybrid atomic orbitals:

[image]

2Py(rot,1): a 2Py orbital rotated 30 degrees clockwise

[image]

[image]

-2Py(rot,2): take the **negative** of 2Py, which is then rotated 30 degrees counterclockwise

[image][image]

Can someone provide a **visual** (picture) showing the "mixing" of the atomic orbitals to create the three hybrid orbitals (while maintaining the same orientation of BH3 as in my first image)?

**EDIT:** Feodoran helped me clear my confusion regarding the first hybrid wavefunction. If possible, I would still be interested if someone could display the formation of the hybrid wavefunctions with some visuals.

Comment: How do you define 2Py(rot,1) and 2Py(rot,2) ?

Comment: @Maurice 2Py(rot,1) is a 2Py orbital rotated 30 degrees clockwise. -2Py(rot,2) is achieved by taking the NEGATIVE of 2Py which is then rotated 30 degrees counterclockwise. This is done to match the angles in BH3. The B-H bonds in 2nd and 3rd quadrant is 30 degrees from the y-axis. I have the specific equations describing each rotation, but didn't post them.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi Yes...ultimately those are linear combinations of unrotated Px and Py as I have shown in the equations. But my problem is not with chi2 or chi3 but with chi1.

Comment: $\chi_1$ is oriented along the $x$ axis, on which one of the $\ce{B-H}$ bonds lies. What do you mean by "opposite direction"? Rotation of the $p_x$ orbital by 180° around the $z$ or $y$ axis results in the same orbital, just with a sign change. But the sign is arbitrary anyway. So there is not "wrong" direction, both are fine.

Comment: @Feodoran  I thought that since the right lobe of 2Px is positive, shouldn't the 2s also be positive (same phase) for the atomic orbitals to combine? I'm not understanding how the sign is arbitrary.

Comment: The 2s orbital can be either one, positiv or negativ. Of course the relative phase of the atomic orbitals is important (same sign for bonding interaction), but the overall phase (plus or minus) of the hybrid orbital does not matter. For the observable (the probability density) the sign is lost when taking the absolute square of the wave function.

Comment: @Feodoran If we let the 2s orbital be positive doesn't it then interact with the positive lobe of 2Px, making a hybrid orbital with a large positive lobe pointing to the right? Thus allowing the positive 1s orbital of Hydrogen be able to interact with it, and make a bond pointing in the positive x-axis (like my first image). If I were to make the 2s orbital negative, we would get a hybrid orbital with a large negative lobe pointing to the left. How would a positive 1s orbital (of a hydrogen atom on the right) interact in the second case (while maintaining the proper geometry)?

Comment: You are only changing one orbitals sign. This will result in qualitatively different molecular orbitals that may not contribute to the bonding. Relative phase needs to be the same, so either you change all signs or none! $\chi_1=\phi_1-\phi_2$ is the "same" (except for the overall sign) as $-\chi_1=-\phi_i+\phi_2$, but something very different than $\chi_2=\phi_1+\phi_2$.

Comment: @Feodoran Ok I think I finally see what you mean. So the chi1 I posted is the "same" as 2s-2Px. The general direction seems to be the same, as long as we negate the entire hybrid.